# @Autowired annotation missing in .class file

Tags: java, spring, build, maven-3, spring-annotations

I seem to have come across a wierd behaviour of the java compiler.
Basically I had below code in a java class

```
@Autowired
SubProcessDao subProcessDao;

@Autowired
ProcessDao processDao;

public void startProcess(BatchDetail batchDetail){
processDao.process(batchDetail.getCode());//// Line1
}
```

When it got deployed to the server by our build team,
above piece of code
started failing at Line 1 where processDao calls process method
because of Null pointer exception.

I was surprised seeing this as it was working perfectly fine on all machicnes and code looked fine as well..But In further investigation I found that .class file for the above which was present in the war file seemed to have missing @Autowired annotation for processDao...
'.class' file when decompiled looked like below:

```
@Autowired
SubProcessDao subProcessDao;
ProcessDao processDao;
```

see the missing @Autowired annotaion on ProcessDao.
In svn repository from where the build team build code ,there has never been a instance when @Autowired annotation was missing from the ProcessDao.
Has anyone every faced this kind of issue ?Or can someone explaing such kind of behaviour

java version used here is 1.6.27 and build tool used is maven

Comment: deployed another version ?

Comment: well we use svn to build the code so dont think this should be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in ProcessDao class you forgot to declare it as Spring bean using for example @Component

Comment: well it wasnt the case..Since the processdao was created ,@Component was present on the file.